# Jekyll pagination and tagging not working on live site

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I've been running website on jekyll, and got stuck in a problem.

We're facing an issue on our website https://www.door3.com/blog/,
We are concerned about the Jekyll plugins. Locally, the pagination and tagging are good, however, they aren't shown on the live site. The plugins don't appear to be functioning live. We are use the plugins "jekyll-paginate-v2, jekyll-tagging." and etc
When modifications are published from Siteleaf, the website displays a 404 error page. Attached a screenshot of the error message as well. Could you please look into this?, which also might be the problem.
[!screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvzQb.png)

thanks in advance for your help. quite stuck here.

The pagination is working fine on the https://www.door3.com/news/ page. I have tried multiple solutions but, ain't able to get to the root of the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.